# Roberts Operator just makes the image brighter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I posted another question about the Roberts operator, but I decided to post a new one since my code has changed significantly since that time.

My code runs, but it does not generate the correct image, instead the image becomes slightly brighter.

I have not found a mistake in the algorithm, but I know this is not the correct output. If I compare this program's output to `edge(<image matrix>,'roberts',<threshold>);`, or to images on wikipedia, it looks nothing like the effect of the roberts operator shown there.

code:

```
function [] = Robertize(filename)

Img = imread(filename);
NewImg = Img;

SI = size(Img);

I_W = SI(2)
I_H = SI(1) 

Robertsx = [1,0;0,-1];
Robertsy = [0,-1;1,0];

M_W = 2; % do not need the + 1, I assume the for loop means while <less than or equal to>

% x and y are reversed... 

    for y=1 : I_H
        for x=1 : I_W 

            S = 0;

            for M_Y = 1 : M_W
                for M_X = 1 : M_W


                    if (x + M_X - 1  < 1) || (x + M_X - 1 > I_W)
                       S = 0;      
                       %disp('out of range, x');

                       continue
                    end

                    if (y + M_Y - 1  < 1) || (y + M_Y - 1 > I_H)
                       S = 0; 
                       %disp('out of range, y');

                       continue      
                    end

                   S = S + Img(y + M_Y - 1 , x + M_X - 1) * Robertsx(M_Y,M_X);
                   S = S + Img(y + M_Y - 1, x + M_X - 1) * Robertsy(M_Y,M_X);

               % It is y + M_Y - 1 because you multiply Robertsx(1,1) *
               % Img(y,x).

                end

            end

            NewImg(y,x) = S;
        end


    end  


imwrite(NewImg,'Roberts.bmp');
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misinterpreting how the Roberts Cross operator works. Use [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberts_Cross) as a guide. Notice that it states that you convolve the original image *separately* with the X and Y operator. Then, you may calculate the final gradient (i.e. "total edge content") value by taking the square root of the sum of squares of the two (x and y) gradient values for a particular pixel. You're presently summing the x and y values into a single image, which will not give the correct results.

**EDIT**

I'll try to explain a bit better. The problem with summation instead of squaring/square root is that you can end up with negative values. Negative values are natural using this operator depending on the edge orientation. That may be why you think the image 'lightens' -- because when you display the image in MATLAB the negative values go to black, the zero values go to grey, and the positive values go to white. Here's the image I get when I run your code (with a few changes -- mostly setting `NewImg` to be `zeros(size(Img))` so it's a `double` type instead of `uint8`. `uint8` types don't allow negative values... Here's the image I get:[image: Resulting image].

You have to be very careful when trying to save files as well. Instead of calling `imwrite`, call `imshow(NewImg,[])`. That will automatically rescale the values in the `double`-valued image to show them correctly, with the most negative number being equal to black and most positive equal to white. Thus, in areas with little edge content (like the sky), we would expect grey and that's what we get!

Comment: Are you sure that I must take the square root of the sum? The article makes sense, but from what I learned in a class, you just add the two x and y gradient values for a particular pixel. Perhaps the two gradient matrices have the square root built in? EDIT - I have heard that you must square the gradient values for the Sobel Operator, but not for the Roberts.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I never would have guessed that it was going into negatives.

Comment: When I use `im2bw` to change it to a binary image to show nothing but the edges, I get a speckled image, regardless of which threshold I choose. Also, the roberts image only looks like your image in Matlab, when I open it in irfanview it is that same speckled image that I get when I run im2bw.

Comment: Again, this is a problem with the image scaling. Since your destination image is now of `double` type and has values less than 0, functions like `im2bw` will not work unless the image is rescaled. Try doing something like: `img = (img - min(img(:))) / (max(img(:)) - min(img(:)));` to your image before trying to convert to black and white or saving it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and got the effect you described. See how everything looks lighter:

[image]
Figure 1 - Original on the left, original roberts transformation on the right

The image on my system was actually saturated. My image was uint8  and the operations were pushing the image past 255 or under 0 (for the negative side) and everything became lighter.

By changing the line of code in the imread to convert to double  as in

```
Img = double(rgb2gray( imread(filename)));
```

(note my image was color so I did an rgb conversion, too. You might use

```
Img = double(( imread(filename)));
```

I got the improved image:

[image]
Original on left, corrected code on right.

Note that I could also produce this result using 2d convolution rather than your loop:

```
Robertsx = [1,0;0,-1];
Robertsy = [0,-1;1,0];

dataR = conv2(data, Robertsx) + conv2(data, Robertsy);

figure(2);
imagesc(dataR);
colormap gray
axis image
```

For the following result:

[image]

Comment: Also, while this corrects your code, consider aardvarkk's advice on taking the norm for your result rather than the sum.

Comment: Also note something. The 2d convolution code produces highs and lows (brights and darks) in reverse from the original poster's results (after the noted fix.) This is because the original poster has implemented 2d cross-correlation instead of 2d convolution. The fix for this is that the Robert's cross operator must be flipped in the origina poster's code to implement convolution. See any signals textbook or Wikipedia for the proper definition of 2D convolution.

Comment: @Chris A. Could you recommend a good book on this subject? I am looking for something that covers edge detection. I have been instructed on how to do convolution but I don't have a good understanding of it.

Comment: I do this stuff every day, so just "practiced eyes". I don't have any of these books, but I've heard that Gonzalez and Woods is good. Jain's "Fundamentals of Digital Image Processing" is the older classic book but might be dated with the methods now. Dudgeon and Mersereau is great but mathematical. This is probably more of a high caliber reference text. Oh yeah, one more is Horn's book "Robot Vision", again slightly dated, but great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation. You could easily replace CONV2/IMFILTER with your own 2D convolution/correlation function:

```
%# convolve image with Roberts kernels
I = im2double(imread('lena512_gray.jpg'));    %# double image, range [0,1]
hx = [+1 0;0 -1]; hy = [0 +1;-1 0];
%#Gx = conv2(I,hx);
%#Gy = conv2(I,hy);
Gx = imfilter(I,hx,'conv','same','replicate');
Gy = imfilter(I,hy,'conv','same','replicate');

%# gradient approximation
G = sqrt(Gx.^2+Gy.^2);
figure, imshow(G), colormap(gray), title('Gradient magnitude [0,1]')

%# direction of the gradient
Gdir = atan2(Gy,Gx);
figure, imshow(Gdir,[]), title('Gradient direction [-\pi,\pi]')
colormap(hot), colorbar%, caxis([-pi pi])

%# quiver plot
ySteps = 1:8:size(I,1);
xSteps = 1:8:size(I,2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xSteps,ySteps);
figure, imshow(G,[]), hold on
quiver(X, Y, Gx(ySteps,xSteps), Gy(ySteps,xSteps), 3)
axis image, hold off

%# binarize gradient, and compare against MATLAB EDGE function
BW = im2bw(G.^2, 6*mean(G(:).^2));
figure
subplot(121), imshow(BW)
subplot(122), imshow(edge(I,'roberts'))   %# performs additional thinning step
```

[image: gradient]
[image: direction]
[image: vectorField]
[image: binary_edges]